# Unexpected behavior in translation for React

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I have a working component wired up like so:

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
...
const Child = () => {
  ...
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  console.log(t('donkey'));
  const output = (<Box>...</Box>);
  return output;
};
export default Child;
```

Then, I wanted to pass the translations from the parent component like this:

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import Child from '../Child';
...
const Parent = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  ...
  console.log(t('donkey'));
  return (...<Child trans={t} />...);
};
export default Parent
```

In the child component, I introduce the following changes:

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
...
const Child = (trans: any) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  console.log(trans.t);
  console.log(t);
  console.log(trans.t('donkey'));
  console.log(t('donkey'));
  ...
};
export default Child;
```

It seems like I [passed the same function](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html) (judging by the signature). However, the printout differs: the local version produces the actual translation while the passed one gives me *donkey*.

I can't explain why, let alone resolve it. My (weak) suspicion point to the state not being involved with the selected language. Googling gave me but a headache, likely due to my ignorance of the subject, possibly missing some revant info despite looking at it.

I'm also uncertain why I have to use `trans.t` despite picking it out from `useTranslation()` in the parent. I'm not sure if setting `any` to the type passed is affecting the behavior, either, but I can't figure out the strongly typed type (the intellisense only says `translation`). Possibly this may be pointing to the root cause of the problem?

How can I investigate it further?

**edit**

Based on the comments, I can refine the question now.

Passing from the parent like this

```
<Child props={useTranslation} />
```

and receiving it in the child like this

```
const Child = (props: any) => {
  const { t } = props;
  console.log(t('donkey'));
};
```

should, in my understanding, produce the same output as

```
const Child = (props: any) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  console.log(t('donkey'));
};
```

but it doesn't. It only prints the translation key in the former case but the actual translation in the latter. When I execute

```
console.log(t('donkey'));
```

in the parent I get the proper translation too. It looks like if the translation capacity is lost in the pass to the child. I can't see how to proceed from here. (I also feel unsure how to explicitly set the type for `props` as the intellisense makes no sense.)

Comment: What you call `trans` in the child is the props object. It doesn't have a `t` property, the only prop you pass in the parent is also named `trans` (its _value_ is named `t`, but only in that parent). Maybe you intended to destructure it, or access `trans.trans` (but calling props not-`props` is not a smart move). But either way there's absolutely no point using TypeScript if you're just going to make everything `: any` - help the compiler help you.

Comment: Note that would give different behaviour than you describe, `trans.t` is undefined and therefore not callable at all, so you haven't provided a [mre]; more likely when you get down to the actual problem it's a binding issue.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Besides the remark on `any` (which isn't a part of the question nor my indented final state of everything), I've changed `trans` to `props` (both in the child and in the partent) with the same outcome. I fail to understand why passing `props="useTranslation"` from the parent where I'm successfully printing it out won't work in the child. I've elaborated the specific of the issue amending it in the original question.

Comment: There is still absolutely no way this does what you claim. `<Child props={useTranslation} />` passes a single prop _named `props`_, whose value is _the hook_. `props.t` in the child remains undefined and is certainly not a value the hook returns. It's also not the same as `props="useTranslation"` in your comment, which would pass a single _string_ prop. I'd strongly recommend situating yourself with basic use of React and props specifically before trying to build complexity on top: https://react.dev/learn#sharing-data-between-components.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I hear what you say and, knowing your track record, I trust that your statement is true. I can only describe what I see on the screen and if it's flawed due to something I fail to realize, I'm unable to recognize it. For now, we decided to only check in the test if the key is present, without verifying the translated and interpolated contents. Thank you for trying to help us. It's always appreciated, regardless of the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in that you are passing the hook `useTranslation` uninitialized so it won't return the functions. Take a look at this sample that does what you want to achieve by passing the `t` function to the child component:

```
const Child = ({ t }) => {
  if (t === undefined) return "t is not a function";

  return <>{t("Welcome to React")} from Child</>;
};

export default function App() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  const changeLanguage = (lng) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
  };

  const index = 11;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
        <h2>{t("Welcome to React")}</h2>
        <button onClick={() => changeLanguage("de")}>de</button>
        <button onClick={() => changeLanguage("en")}>en</button>
      </div>
      <div className="App-intro">
        <Trans>
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </Trans>
        <Trans i18nKey="welcome">trans</Trans>
        <Trans>
          {index + 1} <a>xxx</a>
        </Trans>
      </div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
        <Child t={t} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is an excerpt from [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-forked-8ns4qr?file=/src/app.js) where I got this to work. In any case, I don't think this is the right way to do it and I don't see the use case for having to pass the translation function to the child. **The right thing to do would be to use the hook `useTranslation` inside the child**.